# How do I make it round off instead of always round down?

Tags: c#, rounding

Here's my formula:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;

double multiplier;

amount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(multiplier * a * (4 * b + c) / 100, 0));
```

When I get a value that would make it have a decimal of .5 or greater it's rounding down instead. How do I make it so that this equation will round off the final result (and I know how to display as a string)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default rounding behvaior for `Math.Round` is `ToEven`, which rounds numbers on the midpoint to the nearest even integer.  it does not always round down, as you are claiming, it rounds down exactly half of the time, and round up exactly half of the time.  If you wish the midpoint to always round away from zero then you need to specify `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` to `Math.Round`.

Comment: Actually multiplier is always floating sorry for got to point that out.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Division has a higher precidence than multiplication, so the truncation happens before `multiplier` is ever relevant.

Comment: @Servy `5 * 10 / 20` returns `2` instead of `0`. And [Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) says same

Comment: @Servy multiplication/division goes from left to right. It will be a double. E.g. `(double)5 * 2 / 4` and `5 * 2 / (double)4` yields the same result. I know some people learn that with PEDMAS, but it's really P-E-DM-AS.

Comment: Ok I made it a double but the problem is that if it's 5 it actually rounds down. Shouldn't it round up?

Comment: @puretppc `5` is an integer; there is no way for it to be rounded at all.

Comment: @puretppc it does not matter whether 100 is integer or double, if multiplier is double. Answer is not correct, and somebody is hesitating to delete it :)

Comment: I mean 14.5 for example. I'm getting 14 instead of 15.

Comment: @puretppc that is because the default midpoint rounding behavior is `ToEven`.

Comment: @Servy -1 sorry, but I think you should remove incorrect answer with incorrect upvotes and add another one

Comment: So all I have to do is just add in the MidpointRounding.ToAwayFromZero as paramater?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Even with the 4 upvotes, this answer has cost me 2 rep as I was rep capped when I posted it.  If I cared about the rep I'd delete it and *not* repost it.  If I cared about having a quality answer on this question, I'd leave it.  Personally, I'd rather leave it.

Comment: @puretppc That is what this answer says, yes.

Comment: @Servy personally I think you didn't care about quality of answer, because it was obvious that your suggestion on operators precedence was wrong. I waited long enough for not downvoting answer, and downvoting cost me -1 rep, because I'm far from cap today. So, who don't cares on rep? :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You waited to downvote it until *after* it was edited.  So you're trying to *discourage* me from editing the answer to one that is correct?  Interesting.  Personally, that seems like a bad idea to me, but to each their own.  If I didn't care about the quality of the answer then I would have just not edited it.  If I only cared about the rep I wouldn't have posted it in the first place, as I'm already capped.  That you seem to care much more about earning rep than answer quality actually concerns me.

Comment: Umm, that's exactly what I said below before you edited your answer.

Answer (score 3):

(In addition to the problem Servey pointed out...)

Be mindful of the mode for some rounding methods. In some cases, you need to use the "AwayFromZero" mode in order for decimals .5 and greater to round up, and less than .5 to round down.

[See the documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) The "Math.Round(Decimal, MidpointRounding) example" shows what I mean.

Comment: `"The default mode requires a decimal above .5 to round up, and has .5 rounding down."` That is not the behavior of the given default implementation.  Also, the OP didn't specify a midpoint rounding behavior desired, merely that it is currently truncating instead of rounding.

Comment: I'm going off the documentation. I may have missed something. (I only browse C# because I know both VB.net framework and C type syntax, so I can knock out a lot of the lighter questions.)

Comment: You have not properly summarized the documentation then.  The default midpoint rounding is `ToEven`, so any midpoint values round to the nearest even number.  You claimed they always round down on the midpoint, which isn't true.

Comment: Hm, missed that. So, it's only true on some rounding methods. I revised the answer, since it is still partially relevant.